# Vuejs works by using computed but does not work using data on heroku

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, computed-properties

My vue page is loading an embed wistia video, the video url is an ENV variable. When I assign video url to vue data properties, it does not work because I can see the url value is undefined when mounted.

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      videoUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_VIDEO_URL,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log(`video url: ${this.videoUrl}`);
  },
```

But if I assign video link to a computed properties, it will work normally.

```
computed: {
  videoUrl() {
    return process.env.VUE_APP_VIDEO_URL;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="wistia_responsive_padding" style="padding:55.94% 0 0 0;position:relative;" v-if="videoUrl">
    <div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;">
        <iframe :src="videoUrl" title="Welcome Video" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess that the vue data is evaluated very early but is it earlier than ENV variable is get loaded? Can someone explain me?

**Note: The issue happens only when I deploy my application to heroku.**

Comment: What are your concerns about using computed vs data? My understanding is that the value is originally blank and has the program loads and the value changes, the computed property reruns and pulls in the newest value.

Comment: Yes, I can only guess that the ENV is loaded after vue data is evaluated. With that condition we should never pass an ENV variable to vue data initialization, but I oftenly see people do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do something like that:

```
{  
    data () {
        return {
            videoUrl: '',
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.videoUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_VIDEO_URL
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can do like this, but my concern is why if I initialized with a data property, it will not work.

Comment: it works for me as well, but it's so strange to rely on the syntax. I'm sorry that I did not make my question clear, all syntaxs work normally on my local, but the issue happens when I deploy my application to heroku.

Comment: Can you let me know what different from these syntaxes?

Comment: @Tiktacaccording to the official doc here: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html . `data` should be a function I think it will work if you define it as named function data (your syntax) because vue in component creation take all properties and wrap them in `$data`

Comment: For the issue in production, it's probably you forget to add your `.env` file in the production server